# TimeSeries has no option for TimeZone over-ride. What is the most efficient workaround?

Tags: time-series

I am importing TimeSeries data from an external CSV file.  Those CSV date/time values are implicitly expressed as UTC.  But TimeSeries imports them using \$TimeZone.  And although TimeSeriesShift allows me to "realign" the events to ( - \$TimeZone) , Mathematica still presents time values with an offset of \$TimeZone.

How might I implement an option for TimeSeries[...] along the lines of TimeZone -> 0?

Comment: Perhaps `Block[{$TimeZone = 0}, TimeSeries[ ...]]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify both DateFunction and TimeZone upon import and creation of TimeSeries.

[image]

Comment: Gosia -- thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sample data is always helpful.

One idea is to use the [`DateFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateFunction) option. Here is some made up data:

```
data = {{"10pm jan 1",1}, {"11pm jan 1", 2}, {"1am jan 2", 3}};
```

Default behavior using [`TimeSeries`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeries):

```
DateListPlot @ TimeSeries[data]
```

[image]

Using the option [`DateFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateFunction) to adjust the [`TimeZone`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeZone):

```
DateListPlot @ TimeSeries[data, DateFunction -> (DateList[#, TimeZone->0]&)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OBJECTIVE: The following string-valued timestamps are to be
imported as UTC TimeZone values

```
csvImport = {{"1968-01-01 00:00", 100}, {"1968-01-01 00:01", 200}};
```

The following results in a corrupted time value 
of "1968-01-01 00:00 GMT-5"

```
TimeSeries[csvImport]["FirstDate"]
```

The following yields correct timevalues and TimeZone, but 
does not work in my production WLS script

```
Block[{$TimeZone}, 
$TimeZone = 0;
TimeSeries[csvImport]["FirstDate"]]
```

The following are correct timevalues but wrong displayed TimeZone

```
altCVSImport = csvImport;
altCVSImport[[All, 1]] = DateObject[#, TimeZone -> 0] & /@ altCVSImport[[All, 1]];
TimeSeries[altCVSImport]["FirstDate"]
```

The following tweak displays correct timevalue and TimeZone

```
TimeSeries[altCVSImport, "TimeZone" -> 0]["FirstDate"]
```